# Understanding "Non type-variable argument in the constraint"

Tags: haskell, constraints, typeerror

I want to convert a trie datat type I wrote to a `Data.Tree.Tree`

My trie type looks like this:

```
import qualified Data.Map as DM

data Trie a = Node {
    label :: a,
    edges :: DM.Map a (Trie a),
    isFinal :: Bool
}
```

Now I wrote this function for conversion:

```
import qualified Data.Tree as DT

toDataTree :: (Eq a, Eq (Trie a)) => Trie a -> DT.Tree a
toDataTree (Node label edges isFinal)
    | edges == DM.empty = DT.Node label (map toDataTree (DM.elems edges))
    | otherwise = DT.Node label []
```

But it does not compile. I am getting

```
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Eq (Trie a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • In the type signature:
        toDataTree :: (Eq a, Eq (Trie a)) => Trie a -> DT.Tree a
   |
19 | toDataTree :: (Eq a, Eq (Trie a)) => Trie a -> DT.Tree a
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I don't understand that error message and the other questions I found when googling for the error were not really transferable to my code, as far as I could tell.

What does that error mean in this context and what causes it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In plain Haskell 2010, constraints can only be applied to type variables, like `a` or `b` or whatever, but not to anything more complex.

Legal: `Show a => a -> String`

Illegal: `Show (Maybe a) => a -> String`

In this example, the `Show (Maybe a)` constraint is illegal, because `Maybe a` is not a type variable. `a` is a type variable, but `Maybe a` is not.

In your code, the compiler complains that `Trie a` is not a type variable in the constraint `Eq (Trie a)`.

Since there is no sound technical reason for not allowing such constraints, apart from it being harder to implement, an extension named `FlexibleContexts` was introduced (see [docs](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/FlexibleContexts)) that makes such constraints legal. This is what the compiler is telling you. You can just turn on this extension, it doesn't have any drawbacks.